# How best to debug "The type initializer for xx class threw an exception"

Tags: c#

I have one user reporting this exception.  My research here and elsewhere suggests this is a static contructor error.  The class concerned contains a number of static fields that are initialized.  I assume it is one of these but I am not sure how to find it.  The suggestion seems to be to include a try/catch block in the static contructor.  As written there is no explicit static contructor.

I am thinking that I should write an explicit static constructor, move the initialization of the static fields into it and wrap them in the try/catch block.  I know I could try this but the error does not arise for me and I would like to send a modded executable to the user to try.  My application does log the errors so I should get a log from him if the exception is caught in the static constructor.

The relevant (I hope) part of the class is here  (it is not actually my code but I can mod it as required):

```
 [Serializable]
    public class PText : PNode, ISerializable {

    //comments elided by edit for brevity
        #region Fields

        public const int PROPERTY_CODE_FONT = 1 << 18;
        public const int PROPERTY_CODE_TEXT = 1 << 17;
        public static Font DEFAULT_FONT = new Font("Arial", 12);
        protected static readonly object PROPERTY_KEY_FONT = new object();
        protected static readonly object PROPERTY_KEY_TEXT = new object(); 
        private static Graphics GRAPHICS = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));

        [NonSerialized]
        private Color brushColor;
        private bool constrainHeightToTextHeight = true;
        private bool constrainWidthToTextWidth = true;
        private Font font;

        [NonSerialized]
        private Color penColor;

        [NonSerialized]
        private StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
        private String text;

        [NonSerialized]
        private Brush textBrush;

        #endregion Fields

        #region Constructors
        public PText() {
            textBrush = Brushes.Black;
        }

        public PText(String aText)
            : this() {
            Text = aText;
        }

        protected PText(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context) {
            textBrush = PUtil.ReadBrush(info, "textbrush");
            TextAlignment = (StringAlignment)info.GetValue("alignment", typeof(int));
        }

        #endregion Constructors
.......
```

Comment: I've removed all the comments from the code - mainly to increase readability but also to protect your assets!

Comment: @Andras  Thank you.  However this is publicly available code from the University of Maryland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the idea you had is good.  Put a try/catch around the possible lines that are throwing, and then log the error before it becomes a TypeInitializationException.

Alternatively, change to use Lazy - this will change the exception to be where it is first accessed.  This may or may not be useful for you, but it has helped me debug similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to debug, that requires minimal code-change (assuming this is a desktop app?) is probably to hook into the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event - subscribe to it in the startup code in `Program.cs` and then you can catch any exception.

Base on the code you've actually *posted*, it's either:

```
public static Font DEFAULT_FONT = new Font("Arial", 12);
```

Or

```
private static Graphics GRAPHICS = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));
```

Given that only one user is reporting it, and if I'm right, - then logic dictates (['once you eliminate the impossible'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and all that) it must be that they don't have the `Arial` font on their machine; as crazy as that sounds.

Or - as I've been rightly reminded (and why I qualified it as valid only based on the code you've posted) - it could also be a static defined in the `PNode` type or any anywhere else in the type hierarchy.  What is the '`xx`' class reported as in the exception?

Comment: Hmm well we can't see what's in `PNode` the base class, which may also have some static variables declared with initalizers

Comment: Thanks I checked what statics are initialized in the base class - they are all defined as type object.  The class xx is reported as PText.